# Transfer ownership of OneDrive file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Can we change the ownership of a file in my OneDrive for Business using Microsoft Graph?

Example:

- `User_1` is owner of a file shared with `User_2`.
- `User_1` makes `User_2` the owner of file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Next time I will ask specific questions with the guidelines provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, but not due to any limitation in the API.

OneDrive, regardless of it being Personal or for Business, is fundamentally an individual's drive. As such, every file on that drive belongs to the owner of that drive.

[DriveItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem) do have [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/permission) but ownership cannot be changed on files in an individual's drive. In order to change "ownership", you would need to physically move the file from user_1's drive to user_2's drive.